# 23/12/2013 is mapping with MM/dd/yyyy format why, why not ParseException

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing, parseexception

Can anybody help?

```
public void dateCalender() throws ParseException{
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("120/12/2013").toString()); //OUTPUT (Unexpected): Mon Dec 12 00:00:00 IST 2022
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("23/12/2013").toString()); //OUTPUT (Unexpected): Wed Nov 12 00:00:00 IST 2014
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Jan/12/2013").toString()); //OUTPUT (Expected): Unparseable date: "Jan/12/2013"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to invoke `setLenient` with false - otherwise `SimpleDateFormat` will try to "figure out" what month that is.
So, first create `SimpleDateFormat` and invoke `sdf.setLenient(false)`. Now when parsing, you will get exception.

Comment: It is `setLenient` (the spelling).

Comment: You are right! OMG, my whole life is a lie! Thanks - edited!.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) **, parsing is lenient**, So you didn't get exception for invalid input.  It converted to another value.

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used
>   by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then
>   the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the
>   format by calling setLenient(false).

---

If you want to get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`, than apply `setLenient(false);` at `SimpleDateFormat`

```
    String dateStr="120/12/2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date d=sdf.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29):

```
public void setLenient(boolean lenient)
```

You need to set the format to be non-lenient.

Answer (score 1):

On the first two:

```
MM/dd/yyyy 120/12/2013
```

The compiler will take this as '12/12/2013 + 118 months' and essentially solve for the correct date. In your example, it comes out as December 12, 2022 (12/12/2013 + 9 years).

```
MM/dd/yyyy 23/12/2013
```

The exact same thing happens. You get '12/12/2013 + 9 months', or 11/12/2014.

The third one isn't technically in the MM/dd/yyyy format. As from the other answers, you can do something like this:

```
SystemDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setLenient(true);
sdf.parse("Jan/12/2013");
System.out.println(sdf.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The question and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20160453/10819573) use the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` which was the right thing to do in 2013. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

The `java.time` is smart to catch most such problems without any explicit settings. A custom `DateTimeFormatter` is by default set to `ResolverStyle#SMART` which does not allow a month outside the range 1-12 or a day-of-month value beyond 31. However, it also means that `02/31/2022` can be parsed to `2022-02-28` with a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu")`. It is only to disallow such a parsing that you need to set `ResolverStyle.#STRICT`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String arr[] = {
                "120/12/2013", // 120 will be discarded against MM
                "23/12/2013", // Month can not be outside the range 1-12
                "Jan/12/2013", // Jan will discarded against MM. Requires MMM
                "12/31/2022", // Will be parsed normally
                "02/31/2022" // Will be parsed to 2022-02-28
        };
        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                System.out.println("===========================");
                System.out.println("Trying to parse " + s + " using the format MM/dd/uuuu");
                System.out.println("Parsed to " + LocalDate.parse(s, parser));
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                // throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
===========================
Trying to parse 120/12/2013 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Text '120/12/2013' could not be parsed at index 2
===========================
Trying to parse 23/12/2013 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Text '23/12/2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 23
===========================
Trying to parse Jan/12/2013 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Text 'Jan/12/2013' could not be parsed at index 0
===========================
Trying to parse 12/31/2022 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Parsed to 2022-12-31
===========================
Trying to parse 02/31/2022 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Parsed to 2022-02-28
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4iz2UN)

**Demo of `ResolverStyle.#STRICT`**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        String arr[] = {
                "12/31/2022", // Will be parsed normally
                "02/31/2022" // Will fail against ResolverStyle.STRICT check
        };
        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                System.out.println("===========================");
                System.out.println("Trying to parse " + s + " using the format MM/dd/uuuu");
                System.out.println("Parsed to " + LocalDate.parse(s, parser));
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                // throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
===========================
Trying to parse 12/31/2022 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Parsed to 2022-12-31
===========================
Trying to parse 02/31/2022 using the format MM/dd/uuuu
Text '02/31/2022' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jy7KP6)

**Note**: Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the format MM/dd/yyyy .So its taking Two positions

U try this way:

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Jan/12/2013").toString());

Here not throws unparsable exception but am not shoore about that is working or not

I think this will be wrong way every time using only MM/dd/yyyy format as "1/12/2013"

Comment: Why don't you delete that answer?