# Kotlin DateTimeParseException

Tags: datetime, kotlin, java-time, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

Getting date from https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches
This date have format: 2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00.
I want convert it to "dd, mm, yyyy", but always getting error:
"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10"

my code:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, mm, yyyy", Locale.US)
val myDate = LocalDate.parse(launchDate, formatter)

var launchDateConverted: String=  myDate.toString()
```

i getting data at String, then i convert it to date for formatting, and after i converting date back to string thats to display at UI. i used different methods, but cannot find the correct way.
My current locale is "RU".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your formatter does not match the input format. Basically you need two formatters: one for input and one for output.
2. The format "dd, mm, yyyy" is wrong: mm stands for minute of hour, not for month. You should use "dd, MM, yyyy".

```kotlin
val launchDate = "2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00"

val inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
val myDate = LocalDate.parse(launchDate, inputFormatter)

val outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MM, yyyy", Locale.US)
println(outputFormatter.format(myDate))
```

Answer (score 8):

### You do not need any formatter to parse your input string

You input string, `2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00` is already in the default format used by [`OffsetDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and therefore, you do not need to use a formatter explicitly in order to parse your input date-time string.

### `m` specifies the *minute* while `M` specifies the *month*

You have wrongly used `m` for the month for which the symbol is `M`. Check the [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about these symbols.

### Prefer `u` to `y`

`y` specifies the *year-of-era* (era is specified as `AD` or `BC`) and is always a positive number whereas `u` specifies the *year* which is a signed (+/-) number. Normally, we do not use `+` sign to write a positive number but we always specify a negative number with a `-` sign. The same rule applies for a *year*. As long as you are going to use a year of the era, `AD` (which is mostly the case), both, `y` and `u` will give you the same number. However, the difference occurs when you use a year of the era, `BC` e.g. the *year-of-era*, `1 BC` is specified as *year*, `0`; the *year-of-era*, `2 BC` is specified as *year*, `-1` and so on. You can understand it better with the following demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-1 1 1
2 1 1
2BC 1 1

0 1 1
1 1 1
1BC 1 1

1 1 1
1 1 1
1AD 1 1
```

***Note:** I've used Java to demonstrate the solution but it will also work in Kotlin.*

**The final solution:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00");
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Format it into the desired pattern
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MM, uuuu", Locale.US);
        String formatted = dtf.format(odt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2006-03-25T10:30+12:00
25, 03, 2006
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Recommend using BCE (Before Common or Current era) and CE (Common Era) over BC (before Christ) and AD (after death). BC/AD is still in contention over what actual historical dates are involved, while CE/BCE is set and also preserves religious neutrality.

Comment: @LabGecko, Thanks for adding this useful information.