# Convert Date String to desired format in Kotlin

Tags: java, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

I want to convert date into desired format. I know first i need to convert into date then need to format that date. My question is any easiest way to do in simple form. Is there any impact on performance? Because i have all these dates in list.

**for example**

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    val dateString = "2021-05-12T12:12:12.121Z"
    val convertedDate = convertDate(dateString)
    print(
            convertedDate?.let {
                formatDate(it)
            }
    )
}

fun formatDate(date: Date): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY").format(date)
}

fun convertDate(dateString: String): Date? {
    return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(dateString)
}
```

**Output**

```
May 12, 2021
```

Comment: If you're not formatting multiple things in parallel, you can declare the 2 `SimpleDateFormat`s once and reuse them for every date. Apart from that, this looks good to me.

Comment: thanks for reply @Joffrey. What do you mean `you can declare the 2 SimpleDateFormats once and reuse them for every date` can you explain me in detail please?

Comment: is my above example is good to use @Joffrey

Comment: In this example, you're only converting one string, but you mentioned you wanted to convert many. What I meant is that your current functions create new formats each time they are called (because they call the `SimpleDateFormat(...)` constructor). You can extract these format instances into variables and reuse them for each string in your list. This also applies if you use the new APIs mentioned by @Arvind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Date-Time classes do not have any attribute to hold the formatting information. Even if some library or custom class promises to do so, it is breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). A Date-Time object is supposed to store the information about Date, Time, Timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. The only way to represent a Date-Time object in the desired format is by formatting it into a **`String`** using a Date-Time parsing/formatting type:

- For the modern Date-Time API: `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`
- For the legacy Date-Time API: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Note that the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>, released in March 2014 as part of Java SE 8 standard library.

Apart from that, there are many things wrong with your code:

1. Using `Y` ( Week year) instead of `y` (Year). Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about it.
2. Not using `Locale` with `SimpleDateFormat`. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.
3. Enclosing `Z` within single quotes means it is just a character literal with no meaning other than representing the letter `Z`. The pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var dateString = "2021-05-12T12:12:12.121Z";
        var odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString);
        var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
May 12, 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9FGVdF)

Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for reply @Arvind ji. what is `uuuu` in **ofPattern**

Comment: @vivekmodi - You are most welcome and I wish you success! Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573). Now, I have put this information in the answer as well.

Comment: if i want to date object instead of string. How can i do it ?

Comment: It is not possible with standard Date-Time classes as they do not have any attribute to hold the formatting information. Even if some library or custom class promises to do so, it is breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). A Date-Time object is supposed to store the information about date, time, timezone etc., but not about the formatting.