# How to parse string (such as "Sunday, July 4, 2021") to LocalDate?

Tags: java, localdate, localdatetime

I am trying to parse a string `"Sunday, July 4, 2021"` to `LocalDate` as the following:

```
string this.selectedDate = "Sunday, July 4, 2021";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(this.selectedDate);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sunday, July 4, 2021' could not be parsed at index 0
```

How can I convert such a string full date to the LocalDate?

Comment: You should use the overload of `parse` that accepts a `DateTimeFormatter`, having created a formatter for the format you're using.

Comment: What did your search turn up? I’m confident that this is described in many places already.

Comment: [Java 8 – How to convert String to LocalDate](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/). [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Tip: Learn about using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values as text. You really should not be exchanging localized strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
String s = "Sunday, July 4, 2021";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, LLLL d, yyyy");
LocalDate ld =  LocalDate.parse(s, dtf);
System.out.println(ld);
```

prints

```
2021-07-04
```

Read up on [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you want to change the output format.

Note:  If the day of the week is wrong for the numeric day of the month, you will get a parsing error.  To avoid this, just skip over or otherwise ignore the day of the week.

Comment: Please give explicit locale with your formatter (use the two-arg `of` method). Ekse the code will suddenly fail if run on a computer or JVM with non-English default locale.

Comment: Good. **Suggestion for improvement**: As already pointed out by @OleV.V., [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573). Also, any reason why you chose `L` over `M` (which is easier to understand)? In the case of `y` and `u`, [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) and it has a strong reason.