# How do I calculate the age from dob using the format of month day, yyyy in java? ex. (March 2, 1999)

Tags: java

The current code below uses the yyyy-mm-dd format. However the input should look like this (March 2, 1999). How do I calculate it or convert it?

```
public class CalculateAgeJava8 {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter date of birth: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
 
        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input);
        System.out.println("Age is:" + getAge(dob));
    }
 
    public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
        LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
        return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
    }
 
}
```

Comment: In other words your actual question is "*how to parse March 2, 1999 to LocalDate?*". Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767 (part starting from "Java 8 update")

Comment: And in the link from @Pshemo do scroll down to the *Java 8 update* since you are wisely using `LocalDate` introduced from Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date string in the specified format e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateAgeJava8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter date of birth in the format MMMM d, yyyy (e.g. March 2, 1999): ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, u", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
        System.out.println("Age is:" + getAge(dob));
    }

    public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
        LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
        return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
    }    
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please enter date of birth in the format MMMM d, yyyy (e.g. March 2, 1999): March 2, 1999
Age is:22
```

Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** Never close `Scanner(System.in)` as it also closes `System.in` and there is no way, other than restarting the JVM, to open it again which means if some other part of your application is using `System.in`, it will result in an exception.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` for this case.

```
class CalculateAgeJava8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter date of birth: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        DateTimeFormatter fm = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input, fm);
        System.out.println(dob);
        System.out.println("Age is:" + getAge(dob));
    }

    public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
        LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
        return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
    }

}
```