# Process different formats of DateTime using DateTimeFormatter to a unique format which is the longest format

Tags: java, date, datetime, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I have many formats of inputs coming for DateTime column which includes **1."MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a" 2."MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 3."MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" 4."yyyyMMdd"**

This should be formatted and giving me a output of the longest format which is **1."MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"** filling in the remaining format with either **00** values if doesn't exist.

This is what I am trying:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(""
                + "[MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a]"
                + "[MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]"
                + "[MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm]"
                + "[yyyyMMdd]");


return
me.setManufacturingDate(LocalDateTime.parse(mm.getManufacturingDate().toString(),
                    dateFormatter));
```

Please do recommend a different way of method if I am heading wrong or fix this problem for me. Thanks in advance and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `String[]`, iterating and catching exceptions?

Comment: I previously did with try-catch block and just seeking a different form doing it to reduce the lines and duplication of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) and keep the optional patterns inside the square bracket.
2. I also strongly suggest to use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--) to deal with case (e.g. AM/am).
3. Also, never forget to use `Locale` with a `DateTimeFormatter` because it is a `Locale`-sensitive type.
4. Last but not the least, note that `H` is use for 24-hour format while `h` is used for 12-hour format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("[MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a][MM/dd/uuuu HH[:mm[:ss]]][uuuuMMdd[ hh:mm:ss a]")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Test
        String[] arr = { "08/25/2021 10:20:30 am", "08/25/2021 10:20:30", "08/25/2021 10:20", "20210825" };

        for (String s : arr) {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dateFormatter);
            System.out.println(ldt);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-25T10:20:30
2021-08-25T10:20:30
2021-08-25T10:20
2021-08-25T00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mQWzRE)

**Note:** You can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Hi For me using the above solution is throwing the following error:


ERROR: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 0

INPUT: 08/25/2021 10:20:30 am

Comment: @RakeshKumar - I have also linked an online editor where it is running without any problem. What is the version of JDK you are using?

Comment: Hi Arvind, sorry I see that it's working fine in demo you shared but I am trying to figure out what could be my problem and BTW I am using 14.0.2 version

Comment: @RakeshKumar - [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) is another online editor where you can copy and paste my code as it is and execute.