# How to change Timestamp String to "DD.MM.YYYY"?

Tags: java, string, date, datetime

I need a different format of strings to convert to "DD.MM.YYYY".

`"Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100"` has to be changed to `"03.11.2022"`

and

`"01.11.2022 20:00:00"` to `"01.11.2022"`.

All the formats are in `String`.

I tried doing

```java
String pattern="DD.MM.YYYY";
DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse("01.11.2022 20:00:00")
```

I have also tried doing the following

```java
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(
        item.getStartdatum(),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "DDMMYYYY" )
    ).format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD.MM.YYYY")
    )
```

But got the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text 'Sun, 30 Oct 2022 00:30:00 +0200' could not be parsed at index 0
```

I tried doing the following as well

```java
String pattern="DD.MM.YYYY";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = format.parse(01.11.2022 20:00:00);
```

However, I am not getting the correct output. How can I get my desired result?

Comment: starting with the pattern, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of `DateTimeFormatter` : "D | day-of-year" - probably not what you want

Comment: The former example can be parsed using `OffsetDateTime.parse("Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)`. You may combine this with one of the answers.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (`LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` are from there).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `01.11.2022 20:00:00` means 1 November (not January 11)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things…

- if you can use `java.time`, use it exclusively if possible (no `SimpleDateFormat` or similar legacy stuff)
- a `DateTimeFormatter` can be used to parse **and** format `String`s representing a datetime, if input and output format are different, you will need two different `DateTimeFormatter`s
- the *Text 'Sun, 30 Oct 2022 00:30:00 +0200' could not be parsed at index 0* due to your try to parse it with the pattern `"DD.MM.YYYY"`, which is wrong on several levels:

  - the pattern seems to expect the `String` to start with a numerical representation of the day of month, but it starts with `Thu`, an abbreviation of the name of a day of week
  - the symbol `D` means day of year, a number between 1 and 366 (in leap years, 365 otherwise)
  - the symbol `Y` means week-based year

Read more about those symbols [in the JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

You could do the following instead:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // two example inputs
    String first = "Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100";
    String second = "01.11.2022 20:00:00";
    // prepare a formatter for each pattern in order to parse the Strings
    DateTimeFormatter dtfInFirst = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "EEE, d MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss x",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH
                                   );
    // (second one does not have an offset from UTC, so the resulting class is different)
    DateTimeFormatter dtfInSecond = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    // parse the Strings using the formatters
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(first, dtfInFirst);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(second, dtfInSecond);
    // prepare a formatter, this time for output formatting
    DateTimeFormatter dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu");
    // extract the date part of each result of the parsing
    LocalDate firstResult = odt.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate secondResult = ldt.toLocalDate();
    // and print it formatted using the output formatter
    System.out.println(first + " ---> "
                             + firstResult.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots));
    System.out.println(second + " ---> " 
                              + secondResult.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots));
}
```

Which will output the conversion results as follows:

```
Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100 ---> 03.11.2022
01.11.2022 20:00:00 ---> 01.11.2022
```

The first formatter will need a `Locale` because of the presence of names (day of week & month). You cannot parse that using any exclusively numerical parser and the language / culture must match.<

---

#### short version

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // two example inputs
    String first = "Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100";
    String second = "01.11.2022 20:00:00";
    // prepare a custom formatter for the second pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtfInSecond = DateTimeFormatter
                                        .ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    // parse the first String by means of a built-in RFC formatter
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(
                                first,
                                DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    // parse the second String using the custom formatter
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(second, dtfInSecond);
    // prepare a formatter, this time for output formatting
    DateTimeFormatter dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots = DateTimeFormatter
                                                        .ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu");
    // and print it formatted using the output formatter
    System.out.println(first + " ---> "
                             + odt.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots));
    System.out.println(second + " ---> " 
                              + ldt.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots));
}
```

---

### HINT:

For dates like the one mentioned in your comment…

```
Text '9.28.2022 6:30:00' could not be parsed at index 0
```

you will have to use a pattern with single-digit day of month and hour of day, probably even month of year if anything like `9.8.2022` is possible. However, you will definitely need to switch day of month and month of year because there is just no month no. 28 in a year.

Short example:

```java
String third = "9.28.2022 6:30:00";
DateTimeFormatter dtfInThird = DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("M.d.uuuu H:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldtThird = LocalDateTime.parse(third, dtfInThird);
System.out.println(third + " ---> " 
                         + ldtThird.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots));
```

Executed in a `main`, this will output

```
9.28.2022 6:30:00 ---> 28.09.2022
```

Comment: Text '9.28.2022 6:30:00' could not be parsed at index 0 ---error is due to the single digit day and hour?

Comment: You will need another `DateTimeFormatter` for datetimes like that. Yes, the single digit day and hour are a problem, but this has a different order, month of year is first and day of month second. None of the provided examples were like that.

Comment: Good answer detailing out the issues. For `dtfInFirst` I recommend you use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. Also you need not extract the date parts before formatting. You can directly do `odt.format(dtfDateOnlySeparatedByDots)` and similarly for `ldt`.

Comment: @Jeet see my edit concerning your `Text '9.28.2022 6:30:00' could not be parsed at index 0`…

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the suggestions, the *long* version was put there on purpose. I wanted to point out the different steps needed, but it is definitely worth mentioning the short way.

Answer (score 5):

The ***java.util*** date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

deHaar has already written a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74319071/10819573). However, if you want to use a single `DateTimeFormatter`, you can check this answer.

For parsing, you can build a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional patterns and default time-zone offset value (since you do not have time-zone offset in the second date-time string) as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("[d.M.uuuu H:m:s][EEE, d MMM uuuu H:m:s X]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

where the optional patterns are in square brackets. Alternatively, you can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#optionalStart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalStart--) and [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#optionalEnd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalEnd--) to specify optional patterns.

With this parser, you can parse the given date-time strings to `OffsetDateTime` and format it to the desired string using the following `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("[d.M.uuuu H:m:s][EEE, d MMM uuuu H:m:s X]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

    // Test
    Stream.of(
          "Thu, 3 Nov 2022 06:00:00 +0100",
          "01.11.2022 20:00:00"
        )
        .map(s -> OffsetDateTime.parse(s, parser).format(formatter).toString())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    ;
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
03.11.2022
01.11.2022
```

### Note

1. Make sure to check the [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to understand the difference between `Y` and `y` and between `D` and `d`.
2. You can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer u to y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) with `DateTimeFormatter`.
3. Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Why is it throwing error if the String given as "9.28.2022 6:30:00", I mean single digit day or hour? The error I got is :- Text '9.28.2022 6:30:00' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: @Jeet - You can use a single letter to parse one or multiple digits. I've updated the answer accordingly. Let me know in case you still face any issues.