# Formatting a date String/Integer number from shared preferrences

Tags: java, android, date

I do not know what I am doing wrong? But what I am trying to do is format my `dateDue` String from `SharedPreferences` to the format of **MM/dd/yyyy** from **MMddyyyy**.

But my code below returns all dates with slashes but it displays the date **12/31/1969** and not my SharedPreferences number, which should display **12/30/2022**. Why would it go back so far? Does it have to do with something with Calendar?

```
String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);

SharedPreferences settings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, 0);
Integer dateDue = Integer.valueOf(settings.getInt("dateDue", 0));

format = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
String date = format.format(dateDue);

if (Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(dueAmount)) > 0) { 
    holder.getDateDue.setText(String.valueOf(date));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Existing answers are correct but missing the solution part you are looking for. What you need is:

1. Parse the date string which is in the format, `MMddyyyy`.
2. Format the parsed date into a string of format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Solution using `java.time` API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdduuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Given below is a sample date string. In your case it may be,
        // String strDateDue settings.getString("dateDue", String.valueOf(0));
        String strDateDue = "12302022";

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDateDue, parser);
        String formatted = date.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
12/30/2022
```

Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "12302022" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdduuuu" ) 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Mike Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911940/642706) appears to be correct, and quite clever in detecting the problem as your Question is not clearly stated. That Answer determined your input must have been `"12302022"`.

### *java.time*

Additionally, you should know that you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To parse your input `12302022` in MMDDYYYY format, define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdduuuu" ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

Use that to parse the string into a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "12302022" , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString() = 2022-12-30

### ISO 8601

That output of `LocalDate.toString` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Tip: Use ISO 8601 formats for storing and exchanging date-time values textually. The formats are designed to be easily parsed by machine as well as easily read by humans.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

### Android

Android 26+ comes with an implementation of the *java.time* classes.

In earlier Android, use the latest tooling to access most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: It works great, but I want to use slashes instead of dashes and you cant rearrange the date format no matter what pattern you put.

Comment: Its displaying yyyyMMdd

Comment: @user20791491 Define another `DateTimeFormatter`, pass to `LocalDate#format`. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. Generating text from *java.time* has been covered many many times already.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through what is happening, it's kind of funny if you know Java.

`format.format(dateDue)` is implemented by `DateFormat.format(Object)` (because SimpleDateFormat extends DateFormat and inherits `format(Object)` and does not override it). The code for that is:

```
if (obj instanceof Date)
    return format( (Date)obj, toAppendTo, fieldPosition );
else if (obj instanceof Number)
    return format( new Date(((Number)obj)...
```

`obj` in this case is an Integer which is a Number, so it calls `format(new Date(obj)...`

`new Date(<some integer>)` creates a date that is `<some integer>` milliseconds from January 1, 1970. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-

And `<some integer>` here is 12302022, or 12.3 million milliseconds or 12,300 seconds or 3.4 hours after January 1, 1970 at midnight, and then with the timezone difference you get 12/31/1969.

Comment: So how would I implement this into my code to work, because I kind of understand of what your saying?

Comment: Start by using `String.valueOf(dateDue)` so you're working with a string instead of an integer.

Comment: I changed it all to strings and it gives me this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: `String dateDue = settings.getString("dateDue", String.valueOf(0));
        String dueDate = dateDue;

        if (Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(dueAmount)) > 0) {
            holder.getDateDue.setText(format.format(dueDate));
        }`