# What is this datetimestamp 20220914171900Z-0700 in JSON?

Tags: json, date, datetime, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I see below datetimestamp in json but not sure which format is this??

**20220914171900Z-0700**

any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!

I used constructDateString but no luck!

Comment: It must be a homegrown format from somewhere. Nothing I have seen before (and I have seen many). It’s reminding of the compact (“basic”) [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which your JSON should probably prefer instead. It would go like `20220914T171900-0700` (`T` preceding the time part and no `Z`).

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for adding this useful link here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 2022 - yyyy (Year)
- 09 - MM (Month)
- 14 - dd (day of month)
- 17 - HH (Hour of day)
- 19 - mm (Minute of hour)
- 00 - ss (Second of minute)
- Z-0700 - Z stands for Zulu and represents `00:00` hours offset from UTC. So, `Z-0700` means an offset of `07:00` hours from UTC. If you want to get this date-time at UTC, you can do so by adding `07:00` hours to `2022-09-14T17:19`.

**Demo using Java:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss'Z'Z");
        String strDateTime = "20220914171900Z-0700";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // The same date-time at UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtUTC = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUTC);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09-14T17:19-07:00
2022-09-15T00:19Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/pgNLvF)

**Note:** You can use `y` instead of `u` here but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.