# Trying to convert from 2023-01-11 18:27:59UTC-06:00 to 2023-01-12T00:27:59.000Z -- parsing fails

Tags: java, date, timezone, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have string date format like below

`2023-01-11 18:27:59UTC-06:00`

need to convert to like `2023-01-12T00:27:59.000Z` (in UTC zone)

I tried the below. I am getting exception `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-01-09 23:56:59UTC-05:30' could not be parsed at index 10`. The exception is coming from this line:

```
LocalDateTime labelTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateUTC, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_FORMAT));
```

My short code example:

```
String dateUTC="2023-01-09 23:56:59UTC-05:30";
final String INPUT_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
final String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
final DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(OUTPUT_FORMAT);
LocalDateTime labelTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateUTC, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_FORMAT));
ZoneId utcZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");
ZonedDateTime zdt = labelTime.atZone(utcZoneId);
System.out.println("OUT PUT Format"+dtf2.format(zdt));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) 
and
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/18157)

Comment: Also, `2023-01-12T00:27:59.000Z` is UTC, not local. A `LocalDateTime` does not have a timezone.  It's not clear what you are asking, and you need to show us what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Just remember, "formatting" is not the same as "representation" (ie `ZonedDateTime` and `LocalDateTime`) - these class "represent" a time period since some kind of anchor point or epoch (ie the Unix Epoch).  "Formatting" is the process of taking a "representation" and generating a `String`, typically for presentation to a human.  Sooo, is your question about "formatting" a `ZonedDateTime`/`LocalDateTime` or converting a `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`

Comment: `2023-01-09 23:56:59UTC-05:30` is not the same as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`, there's no time zone information in the formatter

Comment: how to convert this  2023-01-09 23:56:59UTC-05:30 to  UTC local date time

Comment: `INPUT_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` needs to be `INPUT_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssVV"` in order to parse something like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssVV`; You can then parse it using something like `ZonedDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateUTC, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_FORMAT, Locale.US));`; which will allow you to convert this to UTC, using something like `ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = offsetDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));`.  Now if you "need" an instance of `LocalDateTime`, you can use `LocalDateTime localUTCDateTime = utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: Remember, `LocalDateTime` has no time zone, so can't use a format like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`, you'd have to use the `ZonedDateTime` instead

Comment: There's quite a few examples about, like [this](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-zoneddatetime-examples/#:~:text=1.-,Convert%20LocalDateTime%20to%20ZonedDateTime,predefined%20zone%20id%20or%20offset.)

Comment: Use `final String INPUT_FORMAT = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'UTC'xxx";`. Don’t use `LocalDateTime` at all, and also not `ZonedDateTime`. Use `OffsetDateTime`. Parse using `OffsetDateTime labelTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateUTC, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_FORMAT));`. Convert to UTC through `OffsetDateTime odt = labelTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);`. For output you may simply use `toString()`, or you may define `final String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";`.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Maybe if "someone" could first correct the egregiously bad terminology in the title, please?  That's not what parsing means.

Comment: As a native English speaker .... I would call the entire process "conversion" (or maybe "reformatting")  myself.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern, `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'UTC'XXX` to parse the given date-time string into an `OffsetDateTime` and convert the result into another `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` using [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'UTC'XXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-01-11 18:27:59UTC-06:00", parser)
                                           .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = odt.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2023-01-12T00:27:59Z
2023-01-12T00:27:59.000Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/oz6olO)

**Note:** Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.