# Java8 DateFormatter for pattern "Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00"

Tags: date, java-8, datetime-format, localdate, datetimeformatter

I am trying to format the String date, time and zone information.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss a XXX"));
ZonedDateTime.parse("Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss a XXX"));
```

Please note for project support reasons i cannot use above java 8.

I am unable to get this parse work, ***I did try a lot of versions before i posted here***. any support is appreciated.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00' could not be parsed at index 13
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:494)
    at com.parse.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: year-of-era vs. week-based-year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date-time string, "Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00" has timezone offset of `00:00` hours. The `java.time` API provides us with `OffsetDateTime` to parse this type of date-time string to.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu h:mm:ss a XXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00", parser);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2019-12-01T13:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/oek6Ej)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### What went wrong with your code?

1. You have used `hh` whereas your string has only one digit in the hour.
2. You have used `Y` instead of `y`. Note that `Y` is used for *week-based-year*. The right symbol for the intended purpose is `y` or `u`. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

I also recommend you understand the importance of using a `Locale` while using date-time parsing/formatting API. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked

```
LocalDateTime.parse("Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a XXX"));
ZonedDateTime.parse("Dec 01, 2019 1:00:00 PM +00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a XXX"));
```

What I changed was:

- We use lower case `yyyy` for the year. Format pattern strings are case sensitive.
- We use just one `h` for the hour of day since it may be just one digit (`1` in my example). A single `h` does accept two digits too, though, so times with `10`, `11` or `12` will not pose any problem.

Comment: What is the difference to the code in your question?

Comment: Two further suggestions: (1) Prefer to parse into an `OffsetDateTime` rather then `LocalDateime` or `ZonedDateTime`. Your string contains an offset from UTC, `+00:00`, not a time zone like `Etc/UTC` or `Asia/Kolkata`. (2) Provide a locale. If `Dec` and `PM` are English, provide an English-speaking locale. Without it, if one day your code runs on a computer with a non-English default locale, it will crash. Use for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a XXX", Locale.ENGLISH)`.