# Datetimeformat to handle multiple inputs Java

Tags: java, java-time

Need some suggestions to fix my issue. I have date input coming in 2 format ways(input1 and input2).

```
String input1="12-1-2012 T 10:23:34";
String input2="20-10-2012 T 10:34:22";

String format = "dd-MM-yyyy T HH:mm:ss";

SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat(format);
```

How to handle input1 and input2 using sdf object to produce outcome as dd-MM-yyyy T HH:mm:ss

Comment: Those 2 look like the same format to me, unless day and month are switched in those 2 Strings.

Comment: My guess is the input is actually "d-M-yyyy T HH:mm:ss".  Hard to say without seeing more input.

Comment: Yes difference is month. In above example 1 and 10 but I want month to be in 2 digits like 1 means 01, 8 means. 08

Comment: If you want to show different formats, you'll be best adviced using the same values in two different formats.

Comment: First suggestion is: stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and related classes. Use java.time.

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Your format is very peculiar. Second suggestion is to use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead. It's somewhat similar but more strictly defined so should remove your doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

### You need two instances of `DateTimeFormatter`

You need two instances of `DateTimeFormatter`:

1. One for parsing: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-uuuu 'T' HH:mm:ss")`. Note that a single `M` can parse a month in the range 1-12 and a single `d` can parse a day in the range 1-31.
2. Another for formatting: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu 'T' HH:mm:ss")`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-uuuu 'T' HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu 'T' HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        String[] arr = { "12-1-2012 T 10:23:34", "20-10-2012 T 10:34:22" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser);
            String output = ldt.format(formatter);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
12-01-2012 T 10:23:34
20-10-2012 T 10:34:22
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/F4Q7R5)

Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Good hint about the `u`! I think one can use it with a `SimpleDateFormat`, too… Have to check that.

Comment: Thanks, @deHaar ... with `SimpleDateFormat` the symbol `u` is used for *Day number of week*.

Comment: @deHaar I can see that you have also written an answer. Due to lack of time, I couldn't 
check any of the answers at that time. I will do it now.

Comment: Worked as expected!

Answer (score 2):

### You have to adjust your pattern:

- use single-digit months of year (and maybe even days of month, hours of day, minutes of hour and seconds of minute)
- escape the `T` by enclosing it in single quotes

You can do that the modern way (since Java 8) or the outdated way (not recommended).

Here are two examples, one for each way:

### Modern way (`java.time`)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "12-1-2012 T 10:23:34";
    String input2 = "12-01-2012 T 10:23:34";
    // define your pattern)
    String format = "d-M-uuuu 'T' H:m:s";
    // define a DateTimeFormatter from the pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    
    // parse both of the Strings using the defined formatter
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(input1, dtf);
    LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(input2, dtf);
    // print a result
    System.out.println(ldt1 + " and " + ldt2 + " are " 
            + (ldt1.equals(ldt2) ? "equal" : "not equal"));
}
```

Output

```
2012-01-12T10:23:34 and 2012-01-12T10:23:34 are equal
```

### Outdated way (`java.util` and `java.text`)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input1 = "12-1-2012 T 10:23:34";
    String input2 = "12-01-2012 T 10:23:34";
    // define your pattern
    String format = "d-M-yyyy 'T' H:m:s";
    try {
        // create a SimpleDateFormat from the pattern
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        // parse both of the Strings using the date format
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(input1);
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(input2);
        System.out.println(date1 + " and " + date2 + " are " 
                + (date1.equals(date2) ? "equal" : "not equal"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw(e);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 12 10:23:34 CET 2012 and Thu Jan 12 10:23:34 CET 2012 are equal
```

Please note that the outdated way magically added a time zone, which is CET due to this code executed on my German machine…
For datetimes with zones or offsets, you will have to use different classes in `java.time`, such as `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: Well described! A minor improvement: Never leave `e.printStackTrace();` without suggesting to use `throw(e);`. As a general rule, A method should always throw the exception if it can not handle it; so that the exception can be handled by the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

`MM` is the two-digit month format, using values 01 - 12. You probably want the single digit format `M`, which uses values 1 - 12.

Comment: I want to handle if month comes as 1 then it should be 01.. 10-1-2021 should be 10-01-2021