# SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy") returns Weekday Month day 00:00:00 EDT year

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format, date-parsing

I have a String List [Apr 1, 2019, Aug 1, 2020, Feb 20, 2018] which i need to convert to Date format in the same pattern. When Im doing it with SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy") pattern Im getting Thu Aug 01 00:00:00 EDT 2019 format. Tried with Joda DateTimeFormatter and same result.
Can anyone please help to resolve?

Comment: First, I strongly recommend that you avoid the `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They were always very troublesome and are long outdated. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Second, I recommend you keep data model and presentation separate. Which day it is belongs in the model and is nicely represented by a `LocalDate`.  For presentation convert the `LocalDate` back to a string to the user’s liking, for example `Apr 1, 2019`.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Your problem

You are trying to parse the date string into a `java.util.Date` object and print it. A `java.util.Date` object represents only the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. When you print its object, the string returned by [Date#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--), which applies your system's timezone, is printed. Note that a date-time object holds only date-time information, not a format. A format is represented using a string which you obtain by formatting the date-time object using a date-time formatting class with the desired pattern.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("Apr 1, 2019", "Aug 1, 2020", "Feb 20, 2018");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        list.forEach(s -> {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s, dtf);
            System.out.printf("Default format: %s, Custom format: %s%n", date, date.format(dtf));
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Default format: 2019-04-01, Custom format: Apr 1, 2019
Default format: 2020-08-01, Custom format: Aug 1, 2020
Default format: 2018-02-20, Custom format: Feb 20, 2018
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/kvcXye)

**Note:** Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573). Also, [never use `DateTimeFormatter` for custom formats without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.