# DateTimeFormatter gets confusing results for LocalDateTime.withYear(0)?

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

Java version: `1.8.0_202`
see code below:

```java
DateTimeFormatter yy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy");
DateTimeFormatter yyy = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 3, 3, 0)
                .toFormatter();
DateTimeFormatter yyyy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy");

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
// set year is 0
LocalDateTime year0 = now.withYear(0);
System.out.println("year0: " + year0);                             // year0: 0000-01-10T09:53:03.551
System.out.println("year0.getYear(): \t" + year0.getYear());       // year0.getYear():    0
System.out.println("year0.format(yyyy): " + year0.format(yyyy));   // year0.format(yyyy): 0001
System.out.println("year0.format(yyy): \t" + year0.format(yyy));   // year0.format(yyy):  000
System.out.println("year0.format(yy): \t" + year0.format(yy));     // year0.format(yy):   01
System.out.println("============================================================");
// set year is 1
LocalDateTime year1 = now.withYear(1);
System.out.println("year1: " + year1);                             // year1: 0001-01-10T09:53:03.551
System.out.println("year1.getYear(): \t" + year1.getYear());       // year1.getYear():     1
System.out.println("year1.format(yyyy): " + year1.format(yyyy));   // year1.format(yyyy):  0001
System.out.println("year1.format(yyy): \t" + year1.format(yyy));   // year1.format(yyy):   001
System.out.println("year1.format(yy): \t" + year1.format(yy));     // year1.format(yy):    01
```

Why `year0.format(yyyy)` and `year0.format(yy)` return wrong result `0001` or `01`, but `year0.format(yyy)` return right result `000`? how to fix?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The docs for DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) say that `y` is for "year of era", meaning should never output 0 because no era (AD or BC) had a year 0. According to those same docs, you're looking for `u` instead of `y` if you want the year displayed without eras, i.e. treating 1 BC as year "0", 2 BC as year "-1", etc.

If instead you want to display the era along with the year, that's `G`, i.e. `yyyy GG`.

Dates that many centuries in the past can be complicated because of calendar changes between then and now, so be careful about assuming you can just plug them into a standard library and get "correct" results.

"yyy" probably gave you a different result because "yyy" and "uuu" have special case rules, as described in the docs. Only use those if you want your output formatted with those particular rules.